# Prime ng table using pagination does not respecte [rows]='25' value when selected location placed at top of the table

Tags: primeng, p-table

Prime ng table  using pagination does not respecte [rows]='25' value when selected location placed at top of the table
primeng version 9.x

my implemention primeng tabl using lazyloading and pagination [rows]='25' rows displayed on single page are 25 ,it ignores 25 rows value when i selected the rows and place at the top ,rows displayed count is increased to 28 if i select 3 rows from page 2.

Comment: From the tag excerpt of [tag:primeng]: "Questions tagged [primeng] should also be tagged [angular]" Please read those (and act accordingly of course) before adding tags to your questions please.